# Microsoft Azure - Finding owners for ownerless Application Registrations in Azure

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-web-app-service

So there are a bunch of application registrations that are ownerless on the tenant in Microsoft Azure and I was wondering if there is a way to find out WHO created the application registrations in the tenant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**You can find who created an ownerless application in the [Azure AD audit logs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/reports-monitoring/concept-audit-logs)** filtering by Service eq "Core Directory", Category eq "Application Management" and Activity eq "Add application". The Initiated by (actor) will contain the (user or service) principal that created the application.

Keep in mind that logs are persisted only for [7 days minimum and 30 days maximum](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/reports-monitoring/reference-reports-data-retention#how-long-does-azure-ad-store-the-data) unless [custom archiving has been configured.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/reports-monitoring/quickstart-azure-monitor-route-logs-to-storage-account#archive-logs-to-an-azure-storage-account)